# generate custom sequence in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

i want to generate Custom sequence for every record.

Example: if user place order then order number should be **ORD-17-001**.

For next order it should be like **ORD-17-002** and so on.

'**17**' is for this year. so in next year 2018 the first order should be **ORD-18-001.**

can anyone suggest the solution. i am not expert in sql commands.

Comment: You could use a trigger to update the newly inserted (insert-trigger) Order number value - using the format you require.   Using Partition / Row-Over, etc.

Comment: Is this for display to the customer, in which case you may not need to store it, but only display on any customer output. If you have an CreatedDate in your record then I would use something like 'ORD-' + CAST(RIGHT(YEAR(OrderDate,2) AS CHAR(2)) + '-' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY CreatedDate) AS CHAR(3))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an answer using a generated Order Number, this is generated using a combination of the year of the order and the identity column of the table (to guarantee that the order stays consistent, this assumes that there are no deletes). If deletes can happen then you need to follow a trigger approach as per Anthony Horne's comment.

> Set Up

```
CREATE TABLE OrderDetails
(
    ID INT Identity,
    CustomerID INT,
    OrderDate Date,
    CreatedDate DATETIME DEFAULT getdate(),
    OrderValue Decimal(18,2)
)
GO
CREATE VIEW vwOrder
As
    SELECT 
       CustomerId, OrderDate, CreatedDate, OrderValue,
       'ORD-' + 
       RIGHT(CAST(YEAR(OrderDate) AS CHAR(4)),2) + '-' + 
       RIGHT('00' + 
       CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(OrderDate) ORDER BY ID) AS VARCHAR(3)),3) AS OrderNumber
    FROM OrderDetails
GO
INSERT INTO OrderDetails (CustomerId, OrderDate, OrderValue)
VALUES
    (1, '2017-6-12', 20.45),
    (1, '2017-6-12', 30.25),
    (1, '2017-6-13', 10.23),
    (2, '2017-7-12', 5.23),
    (2, '2018-6-01', 55.0),
    (1, '2016-12-01', 22)
GO
```

> Query

```
SELECT *
FROM VwOrder
```

> Results

```
CustomerId OrderDate  CreatedDate             OrderValue OrderNumber
```

---

```
1          2016-12-01 2017-06-21 10:19:44.613 22.00      ORD-16-001
1          2017-06-12 2017-06-21 10:19:44.613 20.45      ORD-17-001
1          2017-06-12 2017-06-21 10:19:44.613 30.25      ORD-17-002
1          2017-06-13 2017-06-21 10:19:44.613 10.23      ORD-17-003
2          2017-07-12 2017-06-21 10:19:44.613  5.23      ORD-17-004
2          2018-06-01 2017-06-21 10:19:44.613 55.00      ORD-18-001
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, look into triggers. You can make code execute automatically by the database when a row is inserted.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_Update_order
ON [OrdersTable]
FOR INSERT
AS
Begin
    --- write your code to generate the order number here
    --- you can select stuff from the newly inserted row by using "Inserted"
    --- like this
    --- select name from Inserted --- this will return the name column of the new row
End
```

More documentation on Insert triggers can be found here: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a Trigger whuch triggers on every insert
2. Then Get the date part using `substring(cast(year(GETDATE()) as varchar),3,2)` ,There can be many methods,Try if you can find something better
3. Now for the number you need to fetch value of last number and also see if the year is same as the current one .
   If it is same then increase it,
   and if Year of previous record is differnt than the current record,Initialise new number to Zero.You might wanna read about conditional statements,and variables in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I would use following solution:

```
/*
CREATE TABLE dbo.CustomSequence (
    Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_CustomSequence_Name PRIMARY KEY (Name),
    Prefix      VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    LastValue   VARCHAR(50) NULL -- All generated values will have following pattern: Pattern-YY-SeqvNumber
);
GO
-- Config OrderSequence
INSERT  dbo.CustomSequence (Name, Prefix, LastValue) 
VALUES  ('OrderSequence', 'ORD', NULL)
GO
-- Config InvoiceSequence
INSERT  dbo.CustomSequence (Name, Prefix, LastValue) 
VALUES  ('InvoiceSequence', 'INV', NULL)
GO
*/

-- IN Parameters
DECLARE @CustomSequenceName VARCHAR(50) = 'OrderSequence'
DECLARE @Year               INT = 2019
-- End of IN Parameters
-- OUT Parameters
DECLARE @GeneratedValue     VARCHAR(50)
-- End of OUT Parameters

UPDATE  s
SET     @GeneratedValue = LastValue = CASE WHEN s.LastValue IS NULL
            THEN s.Prefix + '-' + RIGHT(@Year, 2) + '-001' -- There is no current value
            ELSE CASE WHEN PARSENAME(REPLACE(s.LastValue, '-', '.'), 2) = RIGHT(@Year, 2) -- PARSENAME('A.B.C', 1) returns 'C', PARSENAME('A.B.C', 2) returns 'B'
                THEN s.Prefix + '-' + RIGHT(@Year, 2) + '-' + RIGHT('000000' + LTRIM(CONVERT(SMALLINT, PARSENAME(REPLACE(s.LastValue, '-', '.'), 1)) + 1), 3)
                ELSE s.Prefix + '-' + RIGHT(@Year, 2) + '-001' -- New year, so we have to restart numbering with 1
            END
        END
FROM    dbo.CustomSequence s
WHERE   s.Name = @CustomSequenceName;

SELECT  @GeneratedValue
SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.CustomSequence s;
```

Note: source code for generating new values could be encapsulated within stored procedure having 2 INPUT parameters and 1 OUTPUT parameter.

Note #2: using just three digits (000) for order number for every year (!) is a bad choice. This means maximum 999 orders per year. **Instead, if these codes should have minimum 3 digits for order numbers then I would use (SQL2012+) FORMAT function thus:**

```
THEN s.Prefix + '-' + RIGHT(@Year, 2) + '-' + FORMAT((CONVERT(SMALLINT, PARSENAME(REPLACE(s.LastValue, '-', '.'), 1)) + 1), '000')
```

This means that after `ORD-17-999` next generated value will be `ORD-19-1000` and not `ORD-19-000` (truncation).